# ESLint error - ESLint couldn't find the config "react-app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, eslint

Me with my team, start a new React Project using the create-react-app bootstrap command.
We add the eslint section on the project but we stuck with annoying error that we never found it before now.
When we launch the command

```
 yarn run lint
```

Here the error: 
[image]

Here the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name of the app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-intl": "^3.12.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "react-app-rewired build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "cypress": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:write": "eslint --debug src/ --fix",
    "lint": "eslint --debug src/",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/*.tsx src/*.ts src/**/*.tsx src/**/*.ts src/**/**/*.tsx src/**/**/*.ts src/**/**/**/*.tsx src/**/**/**/*.ts src/**/**/**/**/*.tsx src/**/**/**/**/*.ts",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -c .storybook",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "upgrade:check": "npm-check",
    "upgrade:interactive": "npm-check --update"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.(ts|tsx)": [
      "yarn run prettier"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.12",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.12",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/storybook__addon-knobs": "^5.2.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.2",
    "cypress": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.7",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-app-rewire-webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5",
    "react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "storybook-addon-jsx": "^7.1.14",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

We also tried to add create a .eslintrc file and add

```
{
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

But nothing change.

Comment: Any code about .eslintrc.js

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In my case, I had another package.json file in a top-level project (I didn't noticed that), so my project was taking the es-lint command from that top-level project instead of the current one. I just extracted or moved my project and it went ok

Answer (score 29):

`react-scripts` should already include ESLint and the `eslint-config-react-app` ESLint config (see [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app#usage-in-create-react-app-projects)) in your Node dependencies.

> You don’t need to install it separately in Create React App projects.

If ESLint is not able to find the `react-app` config, there are likely conflicting or duplicate ESLint config dependencies that were installed outside of `react-scripts` (i.e. another `eslint-config-react-app` installation). You can check by using the `npm ls [package]` command (i.e. `npm ls eslint-config-react-app`).

Probably the best way to approach this is to remove those packages from `package.json` to allow the configs like `eslint-config-react-app` in `react-scripts` to be used as intended (based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431931/eslint-error-eslint-couldnt-find-the-config-react-app/60442807?noredirect=1#comment115371560_60442807)) . If the problem persists after that, try removing the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and then reinstalling the dependencies again may work. Otherwise, upgrading to a newer `npm` version may make a difference.

### Old Answer:

Your `package.json` is likely missing the peer dependency `eslint-config-react-app` which includes the eslint preset `react-app`. You will need to follow the instructions to install it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app.

Note: Even though this is `create-react-app` which bundles it for `react-scripts`, your `lint` script was not able to access `react-app`.

---

```
"eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"   
}
```

About `.eslintrc`, you already have the config for ESLint in your `package.json` so you should be safe to remove `.eslintrc`.

Comment: I have exactly same failure with ESLint 7.x. Would you please expand why lint script is unable to access the `eslint-config-react-app` that has been installed as a dependency for `react-scripts`?
There is a comment in [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app) that states `You don’t need to install it separately in Create React App projects.`. I also tried a newly created project with the freshly initialised lint config and it works fine.

Comment: @elm, I do realise that `react-scripts` should install the ESLint config and a local ESLint script itself for CRA projects (running `npm ls eslint-config-react-app` will locate the config and `node_modules/.bin/` should have the local `eslint` script). I have not yet figured out the root cause of the behaviour you're seeing, but I do know the above causes issues if not met. The root cause may differ from person-to-person so providing a package.json and other config files would be most helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response. Looked into this further and found the reason for my break - I had two different versions of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` installed (one that is coming as a dep for `react-scripts`, and the second I installed following `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` installation docs). These packages had different major version and I assume this was causing the conflict.
Now I went on and removed all the additional packages installed such as `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` etc, and can extend the react-app config as per CRA documentation.

Comment: and the lesson learnt is that we don't need to install packages that have already been installed as a dependency for `react-scripts`

Comment: Thanks @elm for your valuable findings. I will make a general note in the answer in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 19):

The problem here is with the `yarn` package manager. Because `eslint-config-react-app`
is not under the `node_modules` directly and it's inside the react-scripts: `node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules` yarn has not load that correctly (more information [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13283#issuecomment-628513550))

So, currently, there are 2 options to resolve that issue:

1. using `npm` instead of `yarn`.
2. install `eslint-config-react-app` package in addition to the one we have inside `react-scripts`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using `npm install` instead of `yarn`.

Not sure why but I guess it's because yarn install multiple packages at a time while npm installs them one after the other. So maybe some of them are skipped or not installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

My friends, just do these steps in your React app (you can use these steps with **create-react-app** or **vite** app):

1. Install `eslint-config-react-app` as a **devDependencies** (It might be you have this package already, just reinstall it.):

   `npm i -D eslint-config-react-app`
2. Add the code below to your `.eslintrc.cjs` or `.eslintrc.js`:

   ```
   {
      "extends": [
         "eslint:recommended",
         "react-app"
       ],
   }
   ```

You can find this issue in the [eslint discord](https://discord.com/channels/688543509199716507/1098630038133428315/1098630038133428315)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

I solve changing my lint script:

Old this:

```
"lint": "eslint --debug src/"
```

New to this:

```
"lint": "eslint --debug 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
```

Comment: How did you get to start `eslint` directly? I can only start it like `./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js`.

Comment: @lazy.lizard - try `export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"`  Then whenever theres a node_modules directory in your current directory, you'll be able to run all the binaries without the path prefix.  Put it in your .bash_profile or similar to make it permanent.

Comment: @lazy.lizard another way without modifying PATH is to add the command like the above in scripts and pass in the args using `--`. For example, `npm run lint -- --debug src/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using yarn, I solved this by reinstall vscode and downgrade eslint to 7.32

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use React in your project just add this in .eslintrc.js:

```
{
   root: true,
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Removing **pre-commit** file from **.git/hooks** resolved my issue.

Comment: you probably have a script that adds that, so this isn't a permanent solution