# How to solve Eslint error while deploying Full-Stack app to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, eslint

I want to deploy React/Express app in Heroku. The project is in one folder and has only one **.git**. Client folder is in the **root**. I was following to [this tutorial](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/deploying-a-react-app-with-a-server/?fbclid=IwAR375l_CTCoQx5z12iAqQ-hUqNRCVqqtAP0VXcd8rTQ7Go_bhSuwYaUzhh8) , but encountered an error with Eslint, while running the command.

```
git push heroku master
```

Here is the error

```
ESLint: 6.8.0.
remote: 
remote: ESLint couldn't find the config "react-app" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.
remote: 
remote: The config "react-app" was referenced from the config file in "/tmp/build_72772b34/client/.eslintrc.json".
remote: 
remote: If you still have problems, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 2
remote: npm ERR! express-typescript-starter@0.1.0 lint: `tsc --noEmit && eslint "**/*.{js,ts}" --quiet --fix`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the express-typescript-starter@0.1.0 lint script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to install **Eslint** globally, removed and reinstalled **node_modules**, changed **eslintrcjson** but can't get rid of this error. 
It says that **config react-app** which is in **eslintrc.json** is not correct. I have the same **eslintrc.json** file both in server and client side as well.
Also I removed **.eslintrc** file according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431931/eslint-error-eslint-couldnt-find-the-config-react-app) since I have installed and have in **package.json**. Correct me, please, if I am wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.
Client/eslintrc.json file

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["jsx-a11y", "react"],
  "rules" : {
     "indent": ["error", 2],
     "no-unused-vars": ["error"],
     "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",   
     "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error"
   }
}
```

Client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "fast-track-typescript-redux-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@artsy/fresnel": "^1.2.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/semantic-ui": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.11.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --debug 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.8",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.7"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npx prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import errorHandler from 'errorhandler'

import app from './app'

app.use(errorHandler())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(
    '  App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode',
    app.get('port'),
    app.get('env')
  )
})

export default server
```

package.json in server

```
{
  "name": "express-typescript-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A starting point for Node.js express apps with TypeScript",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter"
  },
  "author": "Bowden Kelly",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "build": "npm run build-sass && npm run build-ts && npm run lint && npm run copy-static-assets",
    "serve": "node dist/server.js",
    "watch-node": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "watch": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Sass,TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run watch-node\"",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --coverage --verbose false",
    "watch-test": "npm run test -- --watchAll",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint --debug 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "copy-static-assets": "ts-node copyStaticAssets.ts",
    "debug": "npm run build && npm run watch-debug",
    "serve-debug": "nodemon --inspect dist/server.js",
    "watch-debug": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Sass,TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve-debug\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.6",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.7",
    "@types/mailgun-js": "^0.22.11",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "fbgraph": "^1.4.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lusca": "^1.6.1",
    "mailgen": "^2.0.14",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^6.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.2",
    "mongoose-bcrypt": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/async": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.9",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/connect-mongo": "^3.1.3",
    "@types/errorhandler": "^0.0.32",
    "@types/eslint": "^6.1.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/express-flash": "0.0.1",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.15.16",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/lusca": "^1.6.1",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.28",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/passport-facebook": "^2.1.9",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "@types/pug": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.4",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.45",
    "@types/shelljs": "^0.8.6",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.21.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npx prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "runInBand": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try saving eslint as a dev dependency? npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0 @typescript-eslint/parser@^4.0.0 babel-eslint@^10.0.0 eslint@^7.5.0 eslint-plugin-flowtype@^5.2.0 eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.3 eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.0.8

Comment: @ Sagar Pednekar thanks for response. I installed but got the same error

Comment: I can see you have added these dependencies in packadge.json of server, not in the client is that correct?

Comment: I tried in both of them. but no use. It's weird

Comment: Can you disabling Heroku cache for node_modules                                  heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
git commit -am 'disable node_modules cache' --allow-empty
git push heroku master

Comment: @SagarPednekar sorry for the late response. I tried this as well, but I get the same error. I feel like something is wrong with my heroku or eslint config. Because the error type doesn't change.